# Postgresql: How to relate data between two tables?

Tags: postgresql

I've searched this question for Postgresql 9.3 and seen no solutions with adequate answers. The Psql documentation also wasn't helpful.

Say I have two tables:

- users (username, password, id)
- data (title, description, id)

I've created a foreign key, but I'm not exactly clear on how that works. I want users to be able to see and edit their data and I want the data to be related to the user. It's the kind of thing we see all the time on blogs or facebook or twitter.

How do I create a relationship between the tables so that each piece of data a user submits is associated with them?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial.html

Comment: Yeah, read that as specified in the OP. It wasn't clear to me what was going on there. It seemed to explain queries across multiple tables, not relating their data in the way I describe (giving `users` ownership of various `data`). Can you be more helpful in explaining these various JOIN concepts or even the commands for *relating* data between tables (not just querying it)? My own misunderstanding of this should be clear if the guide seems obvious to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming **id** on both tables is the **id** of the user, what you need to get all users data is:

```
SELECT u.username, d.title, d.description
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN data d ON d.id = u.id
```

If there is no data, d.titlea and d.description will be NULL. If you only want users with data just replace the `LEFT JOIN` with a `JOIN`

**EDIT:** (based on comments)

If you want users to have ownership of the data and if the data only belongs to an user at a time you just need to have the `user_id` in the `data` table. I was assuming the `id` in table was of the user. In that case when creating the table you need to do something like:

```
CREATE TABLE data (
  id SERIAL,
  title varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  description varchar(255),
  user_id references users(id) -- this is your foreign key
);
```

and then to query is once again with user_id adjustements:

```
SELECT u.username, d.title, d.description
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN data d ON d.user_id = u.id
```

Comment: Thank you. So what's the difference between setting this right now with users with no data vs users with? will users who currently exist but have not entered `data` be somehow excluded if I use the `LEFT JOIN`? What's the significance there?

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm not asking how to simply query the data between tables. I want users to have ownership of various data. I want them to be related. I'm new to database design if that's not obvious :) So my terminology is probably poor here.

Comment: It depends on what is the purpose of the query. No, `LEFT JOIN` is there so users with no data aren't excluded from the result set

Comment: @Proto check my edit. You use foreign keys to reference (in your words relate) data between tables. You are not going to learn to design databases from scratch here, however if you have some pratical questions i'll be glad to help

Comment: @Proto: Just for the note, if user_id is unique it is better to have a single table, by adding the title and description fields to the users table. If it is not unique, it is a potential code smell, in that it looks a lot like the entity attribute value anti-pattern.